# How to pass bash script arguments to a subshell

Tags: bash

I have a wrapper script that does some work and then passes the original parameters on to another tool:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
other_tool -a -b "$@"
```

This works fine, unless the "other tool" is run in a subshell:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
bash -c "other_tool -a -b $@"
```

If I call my wrapper script like this:

```
wrapper.sh -x "blah blup"
```

then, only the first orginal argument (-x) is handed to "other_tool". 
In reality, I do not create a subshell, but pass the original arguments to a shell on an Android phone, which shouldn't make any difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
adb sh -c "other_tool -a -b $@"
```

Comment: Semantics: A subshell would be "$( ... )". That's an inline script, not a subshell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bash's `printf` command has a feature that'll quote/escape/whatever a string, so as long as both the parent and subshell are actually bash, this should work:

[Edit: as siegi pointed out in a comment, if you do this the obvious way there's a problem when no arguments are supplied, where it acts like there actually was a single empty argument. I've added a workaround below, wrapping the format string with `${1+}`, which only includes the format string *if the first argument is defined*. It's a bit of a kluge, but it does work.]

```
#!/bin/bash

quoted_args="$(printf "${1+ %q}" "$@")" # Note: this will have a leading space before the first arg
# echo "Quoted args:$quoted_args" # Uncomment this to see what it's doing
bash -c "other_tool -a -b$quoted_args"
```

Note that you can also do it in a single line: `bash -c "other_tool -a -b$(printf "${1+ %q}" "$@")"`

Comment: Here there is an explanation for the `printf "${1+ %q}"` fix used when the function has no arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097745/what-does-plus-colon-mean-in-shell-script-expressions

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions work well. Just pass x/\ \ \"b\"/aaaaa/\'xxx\ yyyy\'/zz\"offf\" as parameter and they fail.

Here is a simple wrapper that handles every case. Note how it escapes each argument twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -a ARGS
COUNT=$#
for ((INDEX=0; INDEX<COUNT; ++INDEX))
do
    ARG="$(printf "%q" "$1")"
    ARGS[INDEX]="$(printf "%q" "$ARG")"
    shift
done

ls -l ${ARGS[*]}
```

Comment: also useful if you're trying to concatenate $@ as part of an eventual quoted string argument like '/bin/foo '"$@"' --opt' and discovering that it just doesn't come out as you'd expect.

Comment: Oh thank god. Been struggling with this issue and seemingly nothing worked. This solved it. Would be nice if it was somehow a bash built-in to invoke double escapes considering this issue comes up a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It's failing because you're coercing an array (the positional parameters) into a string. `"$@"` is magical because it gives you each separate paramter as a properly quoted string. Adding additional text breaks the magic: `"blah $@"` is just a single string.

This may get you closer:

```
cmd="other_tool -a -b"
for parm in "$@"; do cmd+=" '$parm'"; done
adb sh -c "$cmd"
```

Of course, any parameter that contains a single quote will cause trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$@` to `$*`. I did a small local test and it works in my case.

```
#!/bin/sh
bash -c "echo $*"
bash -c "echo $@"
```

Saving as `test.sh` and making it executable gives

```
$ ./test.sh foo bar
foo bar
foo
```

There is a subtle difference between `$*` and `$@`, as you can see. See e.g. http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-parameters.html

---

For the follow-up question in the comments: you need to escape e.g. white-space "twice" to pass a string with a separator as a combined argument, e.g. with `test.sh` modified to a `wc` wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash -c "wc $*"
```

This works:

```
$ touch test\ file
$ ./test.sh -l "test\ file"
0 test file
```

but:

```
$ ./test.sh -l "test file"
wc: test: No such file or directory
wc: file: No such file or directory
0 total
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. If you call the wrapper like this: `wrapper.sh -x "blah blup"` then the subshell gets THREE parameters (-x, blah, blup) instead of TWO (-x, "blah blup")

Comment: You need to "double-escape" the argument if you want the space separator to be preserved, i.e. `"Blah\ blup"`. Try it and see if it works.

Comment: It looks like it works, however, this would require the caller of wrapper.sh to add escapes, and I'm looking for a transparent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, more explanashons:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.sh
#! /bin/bash

echo '$@='"$@"

set -v # "debug"

sh -c 'echo $@' "$@" # gremlins steal the first option

sh -c 'echo $@' -- "$@" # We defend the option with two knifes

$ bash -e /tmp/test.sh first second third
$@=first second third

sh -c 'echo $@' "$@" # gremlins steal the first option
second third

sh -c 'echo $@' -- "$@" # We defend the option with two knifes
first second third
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried many different solutions, a good resource including background information and alternatives is for example [BashFAQ/096 on Greg's (aka. GreyCat's) Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096). Altogether I found the following two to be the most readable (from the working ones):

---

**Since Bash 4.4** (as far as I could tell from the [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.4#n50)) it is possible to use the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `@Q`like this:

```
adb sh -c "other_tool -a -b ${*@Q}"
```

Note that I use `$*` here instead of `$@` because you want `"other_tool -a -b ${*@Q}"` to be one single string instead of one string per argument passed.

If you want to do the same with a [bash array variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) you would need the syntax `${ARRAY[*]@Q}` (within the quotes).

---

If you **don't have Bash 4.4 or later available** or are not sure, this is my preferred solution:

```
function escapeBashArgs() {
    local arg separator=""
    for arg
    do
        printf "%s%q" "$separator" "$arg"
        separator=" "
    done
}

adb sh -c "other_tool -a -b $(escapeBashArgs "$@")"
```

Note that here you need to use `"$@"` instead of `$@` or `"$*"` or `$*` because you don't want word splitting within arguments, so the variants without quoting cannot be used, and you want the number of arguments to be preserved, so `"$*"` cannot be used as it would join all arguments to a single string. The function then returns all arguments in a single string.

If you don't care about the additional space in front of the first argument, you can change the `printf` format string to `" %q"` and remove the `separator` variable. Or you can use the one-liner from [Gordon Davissons answer](https://superuser.com/a/403369/284665).

---

This solutions work with all cases I could come up with, especially:

- No arguments: `escapeBashArgs` → *nothing*
- Empty arguments: `escapeBashArgs "" ""` → `'' ''`
- Arguments with just spaces: `escapeBashArgs " " "    "` → `' ' '    '` or `\  \ \ \ \` (*the last space is eaten by this sites renderer*)
- Arguments with special spacing and newlines: `escapeBashArgs "a      b" c\ d "arg with
  newline"` → `'a      b' 'c d' $'arg with\nnewline'` or `a\ \ \ \ \ \ b c\ d $'arg with\nnewline'` (*the newline is between `with` and `newline`, on other positions it's because of line wrapping on this site*)
- Arguments with special characters: `escapeBashArgs '$"'\''({:})'` → `'$"'\''({:})'` or `\$\"\'\(\{:\}\)`
- Example from [jcayzacs answer](https://superuser.com/a/507179/284665): `escapeBashArgs x/\ \ \"b\"/aaaaa/\'xxx\ yyyy\'/zz\"offf\"` → `'x/  "b"/aaaaa/'\''xxx yyyy'\''/zz"offf"'` or `x/\ \ \"b\"/aaaaa/\'xxx\ yyyy\'/zz\"offf\"`

(Tested with GNU bash 5.0.3(1)-release.)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a quick note for answers: please use `/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `bash`: from my experience `/usr/bin/env bash` !== `bash`, because it may be multiple `bash` in `PATH`. This nuance is especially important for Windows (native, mingw, cygwin).

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/env bash -cl "..."
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP is showing an inline script, but since many will find this answer from the text of the question, which is about passing arguments to a subshell, I'll show that here as well:

(I'll describe it for a **Posix Shell**, which may not be the optimal solution for `bash`, but will *work* in (almost) all shells, including bash and Docker)

If you wrap a subshell in a function You can pass arguments to the function and those arguments will be locally scoped to its subshell.

For reference

- `( )` is a subshell
- `$( )` is a subshell which captures text
- `my_name() { }` is a function

### Simple Example

```sh
my_subsh_func() { (
  echo "${1}"
); }

my_subsh_func 'Hello, World!'
```

### Complete Script Example

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set -u

my_foo="foo"

subshell_function() { (
  echo "my_foo='${my_foo}'"
  echo "my_\$1='${1}'"
); }

my_var='Hello, World!'

subshell_function "${my_var}"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#! /bin/bash
sh -c 'other_tool -a -b "$@"' -- "$@"
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.