# How to open new terminal in current directory?

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, urxvt

When in a directory, I sometimes want another terminal to be opened in the same directory.

For example, I'm in `~/code/someproject/src/`, and I open a new terminal, by default, it opens in `~`, how do I launch a new terminal in the current directory?

I'm running Arch Linux with urxvt as my terminal and i3 as my window manager.

Comment: How do you open the terminal?

Comment: <Alt><Shift><Enter>

Comment: Try, from terminal 1, *xterm &*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very informative thread over in the i3-faq forum that has various scripts/programs that tackle this very issue.

https://faq.i3wm.org/question/150/how-to-launch-a-terminal-from-here/

I went for the c program xcwd which really does a great job. It also works from within GUI programs.

Answer (score 3):

when you launch a terminal from within a existing terminal, the original terminal's environment will be preserved including current working directory and any other environment variables that you have set. This is why `urxvt &` works

Answer (score 0):

I have a really, really, really ugly hack that I wrote to do this.

https://github.com/RichardHum/bin/blob/master/curdirterm

My hostname is bulletMaster, and my home directory is /root/

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers I have seen work when using `urxvtd`, in which case all terminal windows are associated to the same `urxvtd` daemon process and there seems to be no easy way to identify the correct shell instance to get the PWD.

To address this, I used a ugly hack. I use zsh with a `preexec` trick to display in the window title the current directory (along with the current and last command, time, etc.), which I think is useful anyway. I do it with something of the following form in my `zshrc` (you will need to adapt it, see [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727730/dynamic-window-title-in-urxvt-with-zsh); see [here](https://a3nm.net/git/myconfig/tree/zsh/zshrc) for full latest version):

```
preexec () {
  local WD="$(pwd | sed "s/^\/home\/$USER/~/")"
  export LASTDATE="`date +%T`"
  if [[ "$TERM" == "rxvt-unicode" || "$TERM" == "rxvt-unicode-256color" ]]; then
    export COMMAND="$(echo $1 | tr -d '\n')"
    echo -ne "\e]0;$LOCALNAME $HOST:$WD$ $COMMAND ($LASTDATE)\a"
  fi
}
```

Then I just made a script to run a new `urxvt` in the same directory as the focused urxvt instance, simply by extracting the title in the current focused window (see [here](https://a3nm.net/git/mybin/tree/urxvtpwd) for latest version):

```
#!/bin/bash

# run ARGV, with -cd FOLDER if FOLDER can be extracted from title of current
# window (see zsh config for how the title gets put in the window)

# http://superuser.com/a/403369/77814
quoted_args="$(printf " %q" "$@")"

# inspired by
# https://faq.i3wm.org/question/150/how-to-launch-a-terminal-from-here/%3C/p%3E.html
ID=$(xdpyinfo | grep focus | cut -d ',' -f1 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev)
CLASS=$(xprop -id "$ID" | grep -m1 WM_CLASS | cut -d'"' -f2)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19411918
if [ "${CLASS^^}" != "URXVT" ]
then
  # no urxvt focused -- just do the default
  # optionally we could try to extract the pwd with
  # https://github.com/schischi-a/xcwd or something
  exec $quoted_args
fi

TITLE=$(xprop -id "$ID" | grep -m1 WM_NAME)
MYPWD=$(echo "$TITLE" | cut -d'$' -f1 | cut -d'"' -f2- | cut -d':' -f2-)
MYPWD2="${MYPWD/#\~/$HOME}"

if [ ! -z "$MYPWD2" -a -d "$MYPWD2" -a -r "$MYPWD2" -a -x "$MYPWD2" ]
then 
  exec $quoted_args -cd "$MYPWD2"
else
  exec $quoted_args
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a urxvt extension which is keeping in shared memory (IPC) the working directory of shell PID from last focused terminal.

The full documentation and code is here: https://raphael.medaer.me/2019/06/21/urxvt-open-current-wd.html

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar to simotek's answer:

I use [st](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01dCpMBzsmPMKGpuy3qDXVJLH5swg%3A1582498527920&ei=3wJTXq3kN5f5-wTJuKLQAg&q=st+suckless&oq=st+suckless&gs_l=psy-ab.3...183.1805..1982...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.y6Gn80ti1vg&ved=0ahUKEwjtz_S04ujnAhWX_J4KHUmcCCoQ4dUDCAo&uact=5), which, like many other terminal emulators opens a new terminal in the current working directory if run from command line.

An alias like: `alias opennewterm="st >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown"` opens a terminal in the current directory and doesn't block the terminal.

If you're using `zsh`, you can bind that to a keyboard shortcut by putting the following in your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey -s "^[n" "opennewterm\n"
```

which types `opennewterm` and a newline when `Alt+n` is pressed.