# i3 start new terminal in same directory using ctrl-windows-enter

Tags: i3-window-manager

I like the feature in i3 with which you can open a new terminal using windows-enter.
But unfortunately it always starts in ~.
A lot of the time I need a second terminal in a directory I'm already working in.
Is there a way to get the directory of the currently active terminal and route that to the next one to be opened?
Concretely, I would like to start a new terminal in the current directory of the active terminal (~ if the currently active window/split isn't a terminal) and bind that to ctrl-windows-enter.

Comment: Related: [How to open new terminal in current directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/759294)

Comment: I personally start i3 (with `startx`) from a specific working directory, based on the task I'm working on. I also have my `bashrc` looking at that working directory and source a file with project-specific environment vars and settings from that directory. This makes it possible to tailor my entire workspace to my task/project. It means that if I switch projects, I shut down i3 and start it again from a different dir. It makes a ton of sense if you think about it, but it only works well if you don't use a login manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest way is to bind this functionality to a shortcut in your *terminal emulator* not in your WM.

**Alacritty:**

Add the following lines to `alacritty.yml`. You can then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

```
key_bindings:
  - { key: Return,   mods: Control|Shift, action: SpawnNewInstance }
```

**st:**

Apply the [newterm](https://st.suckless.org/patches/newterm/) patch. You can then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

---

But you can still use a script to launch your terminal. This [shell script by Luke Smith](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/voidrice/blob/master/.local/bin/samedir) should work on any window manager for X:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PID=$(xprop -id "$(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}')" | grep -m 1 PID | cut -d " " -f 3)
PID="$(pstree -lpA "$PID" | tail -n 1 | awk -F'---' '{print $NF}' | sed -re 's/[^0-9]//g')"
cd "$(readlink /proc/"$PID"/cwd)" || return 1
"$TERMINAL"
```

You can also use [xcwd](https://github.com/schischi/xcwd) to get the current working directory or use a Bash solution from [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32508).

Comment: thanks I think I'll use the Luke Smith version. Or just make an alias to a command that just starts a terminal at $PWD. Didn't even think about that